# xfce4-panel update broke border radius

Tags: linux, desktop-customization, xfce4, gtk3

Today I updated most of my packages following the release of Debian 12, but after a reboot for some reason the `amd 4.18.2-1` version of `xfce4-panel` bugged the border radius I set up for its old version using the `gtk.css` config file as follows:

```css
.xfce4-panel {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

In a way that it seems that some plugins have their own radius as on the screenshot below:

[image: here]

For reference, it used to look like this:

[image: this]

I'm not too familiarized with xfce4 and `gtk.css` properties so I could not really come up with a good workaround, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

After trying out the CSS Id's at [here](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/theming) I fount that apparently the panel window properties are attached to the `#XfcePanelWindow` id for `gtk.css`.

I solved the problem by using this:

```css
#XfcePanelWindow { 
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

And it looks like this:
[image]